# Confusion matrix : Values for TN are negative

Tags: matlab, confusion-matrix

I am trying to get the values for True Positives, False negatives, false positives, and true negatives for my confusion matrix when I run the k-nearest algorithm in Matlab. However, when I calculate them, the values do not add up to the total sum of the elements for the confusion matrix which is 500. Also, my true negative values are coming up to a negative number.  Am I doing something wrong?

Below are the values for the TP, FN, FP, and TN I calculated

TP - 398

FN - 102

FP - 102

TN - -102[image: Confusion matrix image]